# Getting the event property of Datalistinput

Tags: reactjs, event-handling

Is there a way to get directly, the event property of DataListInput component imported from react-datalist-input?

I want to use the event to extract other props I put there like data-id and the CSS classnames

I tried using the onChange attribute but it didn't work. Using console.log(e) in the onChange,  did not log out anything as I typed or changed the selection

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.